# Angular: css variables are not usable in components

Tags: css, angular

Hi i am trying to use css variables to predefine colors for example.

Here is my app.component.css

```
:root {
  --main-bg1: rgb(26, 28, 29);
  --main-bg2: rgb(66, 77, 79);
  --main-bg3: rgb(93, 109, 112);
}
```

Problem is that when i use this variable in other components it wont work.
For example

```
.some-class{
  background-color: var(--main-bg1);
}
```

How can i make this work in angular?

Comment: Angular uses [view encapsulation](https://angular.io/guide/view-encapsulation), meaning the styles in component are scoped to that particular component. But, if you define styles in your global styles.css (or .scss), they are available globally. Personally, I create variables.scss in the root of the project and declare the variables there. Then, you can use @import "src/variables.scss" in your component and use the variables defined there. You can also disable view encapsulation (as explained in docs), but I'd go against that as it can get really messy in bigger projects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move this:

```
:root {
  --main-bg1: rgb(26, 28, 29);
  --main-bg2: rgb(66, 77, 79);
  --main-bg3: rgb(93, 109, 112);
}
```

to `styles.css` and then it will work

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-9zcyy8?file=src%2Fstyles.css)

Answer (score 4):

Add your variables to `:host` scope in `your.component.scss` file.

<sub>your.component.html</sub>

```
:host {
  --drawer-width: 300px;
  --drawer-height: 65px;
  --drawer-top-height: 65px;
  --drawer-top: #ffffff;
  --drawer-left: red;
  --drawer-right: #f5f5f7;
  --drawer-top-bottom: red;

  /* Usage sample of variable */
  .use-sample-in-div {
    background: var(--drawer-left);
  }
}
```

You can also change the values using the main `styles.scss`. First, add a class name to your component to be top priority.

<sub>app.component.html</sub>

```html
<Drawer class="drawer-class"></Drawer>
```

<sub>styles.scss</sub>

```
:root .drawer-class {
  --drawer-width: 150px;
  --drawer-height: 32px;
  --drawer-top-height: 32px;
  --drawer-top: blue;
  --drawer-left: green;
  --drawer-right: purple;
  --drawer-top-bottom: pink;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Put these styles into `styles.css` instead:

```
:root {
  --main-bg1: rgb(26, 28, 29);
  --main-bg2: rgb(66, 77, 79);
  --main-bg3: rgb(93, 109, 112);
}
```